# Can't make ManyToOne to work

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

how can i fix this?

```
<?php

namespace entity;

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="debt")
 * */
class Debt {

/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
 * */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Column(type="integer")
 * */
protected $value;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="people", inversedBy="debts")
 * */
protected $who;

public function setValue($value) {
    $this->value = $value;
}

public function setWho(Who $who) {
    $this->who = $who;
}
public function getValue() {
    return $this->value;
}
public function getWho() {
    return $this->who;
}

}

<?php

namespace entity;

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="people")
 * */
class People {

/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
 * */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Column(type="string")
 * */
protected $name;

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="debt", mappedBy="who")
 * */
protected $debts;

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function assignDebt(Debt $debt) {
    $this->debts[] = $debt;
}

public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

public function getDebts() {
    return $this->debts;
}

}
```

When i'm trying to: `$em->getRepository("entity\Debt")->findAll()` i'm getting this error:

Warning: require(C:\Windows\TEMP__CG__entitypeople.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\skola\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php on line 92

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Windows\TEMP__CG__entitypeople.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\pear;C:\pear;\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\skola\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php on line 92

also when i delete this part it works:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="people", inversedBy="debts")
 * */
protected $who;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need setup the proxy directory in Doctrine

That directory is used to write the doctrine's proxies and of course need to have write rights

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/configuration.html#proxy-directory-required

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup the generation of proxy classes first. You can enable auto-generating the doctrine proxy classes by setting the config: $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(tr

```
$config = new Configuration;
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver('/path/to/lib/MyProject/Entities');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setProxyDir('/path/to/myproject/lib/MyProject/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('MyProject\Proxies');

if ($applicationMode == "development") {
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
} else {
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false);
}
```